# How does Leibniz' rule work in this equation

Tags: integration, derivatives, cumulative-distribution-functions, leibniz-integral-rule

I am reading through the book [Probability and Random Processes for Electrical and Computer Engineers](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/5636840/mod_resource/content/1/probability%20and%20random%20process%20for%20electrical%20and%20computer%20engineering.pdf) . On page 307, there is an equation which states the following.

With $F_{X|Y}$ representing the CDF of the conditional density $f(x | y)$, we are given the equation...

$$
F_Z(z) = \int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}} [F_{X|Y}(\sqrt{z - y^2} | y) - F_{X|Y}(-\sqrt{z - y^2} | y)]f_y(y) dy
$$

The next line then introduced Leibniz' rule,

$$
\frac{d}{dz}\int_{a(z)}^{b(z)} h(z, y) dy = -h(z,a(z))a^\prime(z) + h(z,b(z))b^\prime(z) + \int_{a(z)}^{b(z)} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} h(z, y)dy
$$

and then arrives at the conclusion on the next line that,

$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}} \frac{f_{X|Y(\sqrt{z - y^2} | y)} + f_{X|Y(-\sqrt{z - y^2} | y)}}{2\sqrt{z - y^2}} f_y(y) dy
$$

but I cannot actually see how the steps are taken to get there. I am not even sure what the first step would be and how to apply Leibniz' rule. How do you apply Leibniz' rule here?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

The upper integration limit should not have a minus sign (book is correct here):
$$
F_Z(z) = \int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}} \Big[F_{X|Y}\big(\sqrt{z - y^2} | y\big) - F_{X|Y}\big(-\sqrt{z - y^2} | y\big)\Big]f_y(y)\,dy\,.
$$
This is a difference of two integrals of the form
$$
G(z)=\int_0^{\pm\sqrt{z}}g\big(\sqrt{z-y^2}\big)\,f_y(y)\,dy\,.
$$
In your version of the Leibniz rule you have written $h(z,y)=g\big(\sqrt{z-y^2}\big)\,f_y(y)$. Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can deduce from the last term that the first two terms in Leibniz' rule must come to zero and I can then get there from considering the last term on the RHS given the $h(z, y)$ which you wrote. I am confused about the exact steps to get the difference of two integrals though. Can you expand that part?

Comment: You are confused about $\int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{+\sqrt{z}}...\,dy=\int_0^{+\sqrt{z}}...\,dy-\int_0^{-\sqrt{z}}...\,dy$ ?

Comment: Oh. I guess not. I was assuming there was some fancy cancelling out of the F's somewhere but now I see they must be contained in the g and we can ignore them. Things like this are easy to see in hindsight but hard to see at first. Any tips for being able to know the right route to take here?

Comment: No matter how clumsy a notation is try to see through it to the essence of it. Imho the authors could have presented the Leibniz rule in a neater way. Congratulations that you made it to page 307 of that book.

Comment: Thanks. It took me almost a year to get this far, hope to finish it soon, maybe another year